# Object life cycle in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a question about life cycle for vb.net object
what's the difference about there two functions:

function 1:

```
Private Function MyF() As Integer
    Using c As New cMyclass
        If c.somework() = 1 Then Return 1
    End Using
    Return 0
End Function
```

function 2:

```
Private Function MyF() As Integer
    Dim c As New myClass
    If c.somework() = 1 Then Return 1
    Return 0
End Function
```

- what is the better solution?

Comment: The top one uses using and the second uses a variable. The "better" solution is opinion based and subjective

Comment: Homework question?

Comment: The first one disposes the object once **End Using** is reached. Same as doing c = Nothing

Comment: @Innat3: you're mixing up different things. The `using` statement is syntactic sugar for a try-finally where the finally calls `Dipose`. It's about unmanaged resources that can be released there. Setting an object to null/Nothing does nothing useful most of the time. It's not even needed for the garabage collector, which is a different topic anyway.

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) gives you a really good explanation. Even with examples (try\finally\dispose).

Comment: Scope ends for myClass at `End Using` in the first example whilst in the second example the scope ends at the end of the function. I would also look into disposing the class in example two as example one handles that itself.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) gives you a really good explanation. Even with examples.

This

```
Using resource As New resourceType 
    ' Insert code to work with resource.
End Using
```

Is the same as this

```
' For the acquisition and disposal of resource, the following
' Try construction is equivalent to the Using block.
Dim resource As New resourceType
Try 
    ' Insert code to work with resource.
Finally 
    If resource IsNot Nothing Then
        resource.Dispose() 
    End If
End Try
```

Disposing objects is something that always need to be done when possible.